# Hmm, why finding by '２' or '2' return the same record?

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode, collation, unicode-normalization

forgive my newbie question, but why finding by '２' or '2' in Mysql returns the same record?

For example:

Say I have a record with string field named 'slug', and the value is '２'. And the following SQLs returns same record.

```
SELECT * From articles WHERE slug='2'  
SELECT * From articles WHERE slug='２'
```

Comment: +1 What is that second ２ character, anyway? :)

Comment: @Jørn U+FF12 FULLWIDTH DIGIT TWO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has to do with the collation of your database:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation_%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT '２'='2';
+-----------+
| '２'='2' |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT '２'='2';
+-----------+
| '２'='2' |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

they should not return the same row for equality, but if you use `like` you are probably getting the same row. using `like` mysql will use fuzzy matching, so 2 and ２ will be the same (afer all they are both a form of 2, aren't they?)

Comment: Yup, mysql did return the same record, as the answer described, this is related with collation.

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of slug? i think its numeric one. If so here mysql does cast it to int, and any ways '2' or ' 2 ' will become 2. This wont happen with string datatypes.